# How to reset cursor after iterating SQLAlchemy query resultset

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, resultset, database-cursor

I am using SQLAlchemy with Python to query database. In my code, I need to iterate through the result set of a query twice.

```
records = session.execute(statement)
# first iteration
for record in records:
    <do something>
....
# second iteration
for record in records:
    <do something>
```

As it turns out, the first loop is fine, but it does not iterate the second time. After some investigation, I found out that the difference between records before and after first iteration is the cursor.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

The cursor is None after the first iteration. Is there a way to reset the cursor?

Comment: Fetch the records to a list first, using `fetchall()`.

Comment: Looking to your IDE/debugger for the answer seems to be throwing you for a loop. Instead, try looking to [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html) Each time you do `.execute` a new connection is created with the ResultProxy, which has a `close_with_result` flag that has the connection closed when the results are exhausted. If you want to keep reusing that same connection, you probably want a different method.